# How can I unblock a blocked file from persisted Memory Mapped File operations in C#?

Tags: c#, file, memory-mapped-files

Like in the title, I performed some operations in a file with persisted Memory Mapped File use, and I saw the file become blocked, that is, it became read-only. What I should to do for the file become read-write again?
I rebooted the machine, that is, restarted the OS, but the file is blocked even.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I used to use this http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker

Comment: A file is memory mapped because your application mapped it to memory and still uses it. It's not read-only, it means only the application that mapped it can write to it. How did you map it? Did you create a windows service that does the mapping? Is the application still running? Did you by any chance change the read-only attribute?

Answer (score -1):

Like in [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)'s comment, I didn't find anything for the file become read-write again. It is like this because only the program that mapped it can write to it.

By the way, the expected answer is: "I don't know".

Then:

I don't know.